# Which approach is better to upload image to entity in spring boot rest api application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, file-upload

For example I have enitity Event with fields name, description etc. And then I want to add new field String "photo" that will be reference to a photo. So it is easy to add new field to entity, Hibernate will update the table of entity Event.

Also I have POSTmethod saveEvent(Event event) in EventRestController class to save new Entity. Suppose, that I responsible only for backend, and I only need give endpoints to the frontend developers.
My method createEvent() returns ReponseEntity. Suppose I changing my method to:

```
public ResponseEntity<Event> createEvent(@RequestBody Event event,
            @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {
    ...
    event.setPhoto(StringUtils.cleanPath(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()));
    // save event in repo
    // upload image to directory event-photos/{eventId}
    // return event with photo field
}
```

And then my GET method will be return ReponseEntity with field photo:

```
public ResponseEntity<Event> getEventById(@PathVariable(value = "eventId") long eventId) {
    // returns Event with field "photo"
}
```

**And here is my question. Is this enough to show image of this Event for frontend developers? Is this a good approach to link image reference to the Entity?**

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in my application, and I think it will not work, you will not be able to send the Event in the body and the @RequestParam as a MultipartFile.

I solved this problem creating two routes, one to POST the object, and a second one to send the file which receives the object id in the path and the MultipartFile in the @RequestParam.

The same idea to download the file, I have one GET route to return the object, and a second GET route that receives the object id and return the file.

Comment: It seems a good approach, can I see a concrete example?

Answer (score 0):

if you can want return an image in object `Event` or same. You should convert to base64

or you can return only that file in body with content-type=application/octet-stream

document refer: [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-return-image-file)